# Why I am getting null when I send a request to the controller in spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I send a list to my jsp page which gives selection to the user. This part is doing fine. But when the request is send back to the controller is null. I am going to get the request by @ModelAttribute in the controller but the object is null. Jsp and controller are as bellow:

```
<form action="deleteAuthorExecution" method="post">
  Select Author: <select name="author">
<option value="all" label="All Authors">All Authors</option>
    <c:forEach var="author" items="${authorList}">
        <option value="${author}">${author}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select> 
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

@RequestMapping(value="/deleteAuthorExecution", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView deleteAuthorExecution(@ModelAttribute Author author) throws Exception {

    authorService.delAuthor(author.getAuthorId());
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("adminFunctionsPage");
    model.addObject("successMsg", "Your request has been processed Successfully.");
    return model;
}
```

the author object coming null. Can anybody give me a hint what is the problem in my code?

Comment: in the select list what it is showing, author names?

Comment: ${author} is this Author object or String(author name or something)

Comment: It is object(authorId and authorName).

Comment: are you sure, if so in drop down what it is showing?

Comment: List of authors (authorId - authorName) Like "5-Nisman"

Comment: ${author} != (authorId - authorName) ??

Comment: Lets make it simple. assume you get a list of authors (authorList type List<Author>) in jsp page. Now you want to give a selection to the user to sent an author object to the controller so that the controller can delete it from database. I need to get the author object by @modelAttribute. But the author object which I am getting in controller is null! This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of sending the whole author object, you can pass authorId

```
<form action="deleteAuthorExecution" method="post">
  Select Author: <select name="author">
<option value="0" label="All Authors">All Authors</option>
    <c:forEach var="author" items="${authorList}">
        <option value="${author.authorId}">${author.authorName}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select> 
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

@RequestMapping(value="/deleteAuthorExecution", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView deleteAuthorExecution(@RequestParam Integer authorId) throws Exception {

    if(authorId == 0){
       //user selected all, so delete all the authors   
    }
    authorService.delAuthor(authorId);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("adminFunctionsPage");
    model.addObject("successMsg", "Your request has been processed Successfully.");
    return model;
}
```

Hope this helps